# 'cmd' Field Definitions sysprocesses MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds, system-tables

I am looking at doing some profiling of connections types and volumes across the day.

I am using the `sys.sysprocesses` to gather the information I require, looking specifically at the `'cmd'` field to categorize connections. Does anyone have a good comprehensive list of definitions for the values in this field? I can figure out what a lot of them represent, but I can't find online any definitions for some of them, for example `'XE TIMER'`

Many thanks,

Comment: I don't believe I can set up Extended Events. Perhaps I should have mentioned in the question I am using RDS with Amazon Web Services, which limits the permissions on what can and can't be set up.

Comment: RDS has monitoring of connections from the console if I'm not mistaken. I don't know what level of detail you get from it though.

Comment: It does, yes. But it is pretty high level. I was looking to drill down into more detail than this provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comment [sys.sysprocesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) is deprecated and Microsoft does not recommends it to use further. Its just there for backward compatibility

The above view has been replaced by [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You would see `cmd` column from sys.sysprocesses is now `command` column in sys.dm_exec_requests and this column tells you

> Identifies the current type of command that is being processed. Common
>   command types include the following:
>
> • SELECT
>
> • INSERT
>
> • UPDATE
>
> • DELETE
>
> • BACKUP LOG
>
> • BACKUP DATABASE
>
> • DBCC
>
> • FOR
>
> The text of the request can be retrieved by using sys.dm_exec_sql_text
>   with the corresponding sql_handle for the request. Internal system
>   processes set the command based on the type of task they perform.
>   Tasks can include the following: • LOCK MONITOR
>
> • CHECKPOINTLAZY
>
> • WRITER
>
> Is not nullable.

Instead I suggest you to focus on column `sql_handle` which is present in `sys.dm_exec_requests`. Below code would give you query behind sql_handle

```
select er.session_id,
er.command,
t.text --gives query behind sql_handle
from sys.dm_exec_requests er
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) t
```